# AngularJS - Zipping the uploaded pdf files using JSZip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jszip

I tried to implement the zipping functionality once the files are uploaded (multiple file upload) successfully. And the zipped files should send to the server for persisting in the db.
Zipping is working fine but the content of the pdf is displaying as empty.

Also tried setting the hardcoded values for the pdf shown below, and its working fine.

```
                    var doc = new jsPDF();

                    doc.setFontSize(40);
                    doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");

                    var zip = new JSZip();
                    zip.file("Hello.pdf", doc.output());
                    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
                        .then(function (content) {
                            saveAs(content, "example.zip");
                        });
```

### Approach I tried for file upload:-

```
 for(var uploadedFile in uploadedFileArray){
                                if(uploadedFileArray[uploadedFile]){
                                    doc1 = new jsPDF(uploadedFileArray[uploadedFile]);
                                }
                            }
```

Does anyone have any idea, how to implement, zip the files on the fly once the upload is finished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should do that kind of stuff in your backend application.